# How to set an image to go up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got a task to set image for the page when it scroll down.When it pressing it must go to up page.How can I do this?
code is

```
<div><a href="#top"><img src="http://www.antisocialmediallc.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Up-Arrow.jpg"></div>
```

DEMO [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xShg7/)

I dn't want the image as shown on the page.It must comes only on scroll down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working DEMO here http://jsfiddle.net/bxL44/2/

## HTML

```
<p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
<p><a id="toTop"><img src="http://www.theperfectshuffle.com/resources/icons/up-arrow-icon.png" width="50" height="50"></a></p>
```

## CSS

```
#toTop {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:5px;
    right:5px;
    display:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:underline;
    background:red;
}
```

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ========================================================= go to top
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop()) {
            $('#toTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#toTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $('#toTop').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: or did you missed $(document).ready(function() { ... }); ?
check update code again.

Comment: $('#toTop').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
    });
this code is not working.

Comment: You want to show the image only when the user scroll, right?
please check my update jquery and try to include all scripts..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31166/discussion-between-agent1-and-yeyene)

Comment: ? no, it is ok for even IE7.

Comment: can you update your jsfiddle? for every monitor, the scripts will scroll to top.

Comment: @yeyene-U just do onething Press 'ctrl' 'downarrow' keys, then you can see there the gototop text is also going.So the texts are overrided

Answer (score 1):

Working demo of the code is here

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xShg7/5/)

HTML

```
<p id="top">
    hesdfdfgdg
    gdg
    dgd
    gd
    gd
    g
    dfgd
    gd
    gd
    gd
    gd
    gd
    gd
    gd
    gd
    gd
    gd
    gd
    gd
    gd
    gd
    gd
    g
    dg
</p>
<p>dgfdgdfg
    dg
    dfg
    dgd
    gd
    gf
    dg
    dfg
    dg
    dg
    dgd
    gd
    gd
</p>
<p>
    dfgd</p>
<p>
    dfgd</p>
<p>
    dfgd</p>
<p>
    dfgd</p>
<p>
    dfgd</p>
<p>
    dfgd</p><p>
    dfgd</p><p>
    dfgd</p><p>
    dfgd</p>vv<p>
    dfgd</p><p>
    dfgd</p>
<p>
    dfgd</p>
vv
v
v<p>
    dfgd</p><p>
    dfgd</p><p>
    dfgd</p><p>
    dfgd</p><p>
    dfgd</p><p>
    dfgd</p><p>
    dfgd</p><p>
    dfgd</p><p>
    dfgd</p><p>
    dfgd</p><p>
    dfgd</p><p>
    dfgd</p><p>
    dfgd</p><p>
    dfgd</p><p>
    dfgd</p><p>
    dfgd</p>
<div id="back-top">
    <a href="#top"><img src="http://www.antisocialmediallc.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Up-Arrow.jpg"/></a>
    </div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // hide #back-top first
    $("#back-top").hide();

    // fade in #back-top
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('#back-top').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#back-top').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        // scroll body to 0px on click
        $('#back-top a').click(function () {
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });
    });

});
```

CSS

```
#back-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: -150px;
}


#back-top a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

/* arrow icon (span tag) */
#back-top span {
    width: 108px;
    height: 108px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    background: #ddd url('http://www.antisocialmediallc.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Up-Arrow.jpg') no-repeat center center;


#back-top a:hover span {
    background-color: #777;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ScrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)() function in jquery

Call this function in image onclick

```
onclick="$('body').scrollTop();"
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/xShg7/2/)

Comment: Can I use that image in a side window as a small pics?

Comment: Yes you can use at you want

Comment: How can I set it as Small pic at side.It must show only on scroll down.?

Comment: The image comes on last right? But the requirement is the image must come on the scroll changing.

Comment: @Agent1 The image appears only when scroll happens. change the css style you want.

Answer (score 0):

try smth like this:

```
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= "250") $('#your_div').fadeIn("slow");
```

it means that if you lower than 249 from the top you will gain the button

```
     $('#your_div').click(function () {
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 300);
        return false;
    });
```

so after you click it you will go up through 0,3 sec.

Answer (score 0):

put image as hidden,

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
   $('img').show().animate();
```

}
    });

demo on http://jsfiddle.net/xShg7/4/